# Visual Studio Code: How do I delete a row of text if a string found on that row?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to use visual studio code to find a string of text and delete that whole row if the string of text is detected.

Comment: This is not really usefull but just use cmd-f(mac) and control-f(windows)

Comment: type the text you want to find in the Find dialog, click in the editor, `Select All Occurrences`, cursor left, ctrl+X

Comment: If you have a vim extension, such as `vscodevim`, you could use `:g /string of text/d` See https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-delete-line-vim

Comment: Enter your text into the Find widget, Alt+Enter to select all matches, Ctrl+L to select the entire line each match is on, and Ctrl+X to cut that line.  All without leaving the find widget.

Answer (score 5):

1. Enter your text in the Find widget
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to select all find matches
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to select the entire line each match is on
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to cut those lines

All from the find widget, i.e., you don't need to move focus.  @rioV8's version works as well with the only difference that you switch focus to the editor during the sequence otherwise essentially the same.

[image: find and cut all matches]